# Froala Editor use generic properties and add custom one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, froala

I have some Froala Editor inputs and I want to use generic propierties for all of them and then add some custom properties according to the current input.

For assign the froala object I use this code:

```
new FroalaEditor('.froala-editor-inline-horari', {
            toolbarInline: true,
            placeholderText: 'Editar',
            toolbarButtons: [
                ['bold', 'italic'],
                ['textColor', 'backgroundColor']
            ],
            events: {
                contentChanged: function () {
                    guardarFila(this);
                }
            },
            spellcheck: false
        });
```

I want to use some generic properties as a constant like:

```
const FROALA_PROPERTIES = {
            toolbarInline: true,
            placeholderText: 'Editar',
            toolbarButtons: [
                ['bold', 'italic'],
                ['textColor', 'backgroundColor']
            ],
            events: {
                contentChanged: function () {
                    guardarFila(this);
                }
            },
            spellcheck: false
        });
```

and then add to this object some modification like:

```
events: {
     initialized: function () {
           this.html.set('some value');
     }
```

so, in this example I want to obtain the first object `FROALA_PROPERTIES` plus the new `events: {...}` key.

Is it this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself because I found the solution. I can add this keys and values or functions by the next code:

```
FROALA_PROPERTIES.events.initialized = function () {
       this.html.set('some value');
 }
```

But if events key doesnt exist, then I need to create it first.

I based my andwer by this web research: http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object.html